# variable = movie clip in the array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an array thats contains movie clips, I have a variable selected. I wont when the movie clips is clicked variable selected = this movie clips

in as2 I use

```
selected = this.getDepth();
```

How in as3.0?

Comment: R u finding errors?

Comment: AS2 this.getDepth() = AS3 this.parent.getChildIndex(this)